# Cocoapods development pods framework won't build independently

Tags: ios, frameworks, cocoapods

I have a iOS framework set up as a development pod in cocoapods. This project has a xcodeproj file inside it, however I noticed I cannot build the framework from this file. Why is that? Does this .xcodeproj file play no part in cocoapods? Can I change this file to make a build of this framework independent of cocoapods?

Comment: How did you generate the project? What error messages are you getting?

Comment: hmm the project file doesn't even have a "framework" target... I think that the pods project (generated by cocoapods) has all the build info for this and this xcodeproj file is not used by cocoapods at all ..